# Angular missing dependencies

Tags: angular, firebase

I m trying to build an angular login app, but when I try to serve the app I get the error:
ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/fire" has missing dependencies:

- rxjs
- rxjs/operators
- @angular/core

I have installed angular firebase and @angular/fire.
I started working with angular 1 week ago, so this is kinda confusing. I tried other solutions on the web and they didn't work. Any suggestion? Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you do npm install in which your package.json file located. and which angular version are you using ?

Comment: It requires you to install those packages listed there.

Comment: Already did install them, there's gotta be something else. I am using Angular CLI: 10.0.8 and Angular: 10.0.14

Comment: Fixed: deleted node_modules folder and after I ran npm install.